# Can a MS Graph background/daemon app impersonate a user account without user interaction

Tags: sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api, office365, sharepoint-online

Can a MS Graph daemon application impersonate a user account (my account) for a call without user interaction?

**Background**

1. I'm intending to use the [`/search/query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) endpoint which doesn't support application permissions.
2. The app/principal does have the required delegated permissions that's with tenant-wide consent.
3. The same user account (mine) will make each call requiring delegated permission.
4. I can't run the app with the [ROPC authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) since we use MFA.
5. This can't be a browser application - the intent is to have it run without user interaction. It's being run using an Azure function.
6. Attempting the [on-behalf-of auth flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) "appears" to return a consent browser prompt despite tenant-wide consent seemingly active via the azure portal. I may be going about it incorrectly though.
7. Attempting the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) also appears to return a consent browser despite the `prompt=none` parameter being set. I may also be going about this one incorrectly.

**Objective**

The intent is to get the SharePoint membership for a large list of users for site collections and subsites - specifically sites they're active in (hopefully also down to list/library memberships). I'm open to alternate approaches.

My current approach is to using the `/search/query` endpoint across the tenant to identify recently created/modified content for each user, then pull site information from results - and hopefully also granular list/library/content permission for each user. There are a significant number of sites & subsites to comb through, so it may be inefficient to attempt looping membership rosters for each site.

Comment: Did you find out how to do it? I can't use client_credentials, because I need access to permissions that are delegated, means I can only query while being "logged" as a licensed user.
However I want to run a cronjob so I can't use on-behalf-of-auth-flow because I don't want any end-user . And I can't figure out how to make work auth-code-flow without prompt login...
Any solution? Please thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) for this scenario where
   demon apps call MS Graph without user interaction.
2. The code sample which can help you was [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/ms-identity-python-webapp/) and was developed
   in python.
3. Instead of [/search/query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) you can use `$filter` query parameter.
   Please refer [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) for more information.